# Spring Boot 2.3 and Spring Security 5 - Support UserDetailsService and OAuth2 in one schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm building a Java webapp using Spring Boot 2.3.x, Spring Security 5 and Thymeleaf, running on Java 11.

The app needs to support user accounts of some kind. As a starting point, I followed the approach used by John Thompson (a.k.a. Spring Framework Guru) in his "[Spring Security Core: Beginner to Guru](https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-security-core-beginner-to-guru/?referralCode=306F288EB78688C0F3BC)" course. John's approach uses Spring Data JPA and HTTP Basic authentication, where I implement the Spring interface `UserDetailsService` and allow the app to load user credentials (username, password, roles, authorities) from the database on demand during HTTP Basic authentication. This all works well. Because I store each user's roles/authorities in my database, I have full control and can use them with Spring Security method-level annotations like this: `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user.details.read')")`. Again, this all works great.

The problem with John's approach from the course material is that I'm limited to HTTP Basic and storing/managing all user passwords.

Yesterday I experimented with the OAuth 2.0 features of Spring Security 5 to 'login with Facebook'. I used some of the code from [this tutorial page](https://medium.com/@mail2rajeevshukla/spring-security-5-3-oauth2-integration-with-facebook-along-with-form-based-login-767e10b02dbc) to get started. In isolation, this works well for my application to authenticate a user as a Facebook member. **Unfortunately, this supplies a different kind of `@AuthenticationPrincipal` object that contains roles and authorities that are only relevant to Facebook.**

### THE PROBLEM

I now have two disconnected types of users:

1. HTTP Basic authenticated users, whose credentials, roles and authorities I manage. Their roles/authorites are appropriate for my application.
2. OAuth2 authenticated users, whose credentials, roles and authorities are out of my control. Their roles/authorities are unrelated (and irrelevant) for my application.

The end-state I want is:

- My application database stores the roles/authorities assigned to each user
- The application will support authentication via either HTTP Basic OR OAuth2 (to Facebook initially), but my application database will supply the roles/authorities
- The 'unique identifier' for each user will be their email address (Facebook OAuth2 supplies this as an attribute), so I hope this can be used to associate the HTTP Basic and OAuth2 authentication objects
- A user **could** setup both HTTP Basic and OAuth2 for their account, and if so, they can login with either method. Either way, they will still have the same role/authorities in my app.

To summarize: **I just want Facebook OAuth2 to confirm 'this is an active Facebook user whose email address is xyz@example.com' and then link their Facebook account with a user account in my application.**

### WHAT NEXT?

Spring does a great job of providing 'reasonable defaults' for the components of each of the separate use-cases (HTTP Basic versus OAuth2). I suspect that I'll need to override and/or disable some of these component behaviors to get what I'm looking for. I just don't know where to start.

### CODE SO FAR

I've provided some code samples below of the pieces I have working. As I mentioned above, the parts related to `UserDetailsService` and the JPA entities that feed that service already work well. My question is essentially 'How do I incorporate OAuth2 into what already works?'.

*My `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation class*

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> {
                    authorize
                        // The following paths do not require the user to be authenticated by Spring Security
                        .antMatchers("/", "/favicon.ico", "/login", "/login-form", "/vendor/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                        // Allow anonymous access to webjars
                        .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
                        // Allow anonymous access to all enabled actuators
                        .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                        // This should only be relevant in a non-production environment
                        .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
                })
                // All other request paths not covered by the list above can only be viewed by an authenticated user
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                // Explicitly defining a login and logout configurer will implicitly disable
                // the built-in login/logout forms provided by Spring
                .formLogin(loginConfigurer -> {
                    // If the user enters the path "/login", then display the main page (at "/").
                    // The main page contains a login form.
                    loginConfigurer
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                            //.loginPage("/").permitAll()
                            .loginPage("/login-form").permitAll()
                            //.successForwardUrl("/")
                            //.defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/formLoginSuccess")
                            // Add an 'error' parameter to the success URL so a Thymeleaf template
                            // could conditionally display something if a login failure occurs
                            .failureUrl("/?error");
                })
                .logout(logoutConfigurer -> {
                    // If the user enters the path "/logout", then log them out and then navigate to the main page
                    logoutConfigurer
                            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
                            // Add a 'logout' parameter to the success URL so the Thymeleaf template
                            // can conditionally display a friendly message upon successful logout
                            .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                            .permitAll();
                })
                // Use HTTP Basic authentication
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .loginPage("/login-form").permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/oauth2LoginSuccess", true)
            .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .and()
                .csrf()
                    // CSRF will break the H2 console, so ignore it
                    .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                    // The OAuth2 tutorial for Facebook says that CSRF will interfere with "/logout" via HTTP GET (I never confirmed that)
                    // REFERENCE: https://medium.com/@mail2rajeevshukla/spring-security-5-3-oauth2-integration-with-facebook-along-with-form-based-login-767e10b02dbc
                    .ignoringAntMatchers("/logout")
            .and()
                // Needed to allow the H2 console to function correctly
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

*Controller for my login form that supports either 'Login with Facebook' or HTTP Basic*

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class LoginFormController {

    @Autowired
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oauth2AuthorizedClientService;

    @RequestMapping("/login-form")
    public String getLoginForm() {
        return "login-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/oauth2LoginSuccess")
    public String getOauth2LoginInfo(
            Model model,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) {

        log.info("USER AUTHENTICATED WITH OAUTH2");

        // This will be something like 'facebook' or 'google' - describes the service that supplied the token
        log.info("auth token 'authorized client registration id': [{}]", authenticationToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId());
        // A unique id for this user on the service that supplied the token (this is a long integer value on Facebook)
        log.info("auth token 'name': [{}]", authenticationToken.getName());

        if (!(authenticationToken.getPrincipal() instanceof OAuth2User)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Expected principal object to be of type '" + OAuth2User.class.getName() + "'");
        }
        final OAuth2User oauth2User = authenticationToken.getPrincipal();
        // 'oauth2User.getName()' returns the same long integer value on Facebook as the call to 'authenticationToken.getName()'
        log.info("oauth2User 'name': [{}]", oauth2User.getName());
        for (String key : oauth2User.getAttributes().keySet()) {
            // For Facebook OAuth2, the 'email' attribute is most important to me.
            // The 'name' attribute may also be useful. It contains a user-friendly name like 'Jim Tough'.
            log.info("oauth2User '{}' attribute value: [{}]", key, oauth2User.getAttributes().get(key));
        }

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client =
                oauth2AuthorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                        authenticationToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                        authenticationToken.getName());
        log.info("Client token value: [{}]", client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());

        model.addAttribute("authenticatedUsername", oauth2User.getAttribute("email"));
        model.addAttribute("authenticationType", "OAuth2");
        model.addAttribute("oauth2Provider", authenticationToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId());

        return "login-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/formLoginSuccess")
    public String getFormLoginInfo(
            Model model,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal Authentication authentication) {

        log.info("USER AUTHENTICATED WITH HTTP BASIC");

        if (!(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Expected principal object to be of type '" + UserDetails.class.getName() + "'");
        }
        // In form-based login flow you get UserDetails as principal
        final UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

        model.addAttribute("authenticatedUsername", userDetails.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("authenticationType", "HttpBasic");
        model.addAttribute("oauth2Provider", null);

        return "login-form";
    }

}
```

*My `UserDetailsService` implementation class (for HTTP Basic auth)*

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class JPAUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        log.debug("Retrieving user details for [{}] from database", username);
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() ->
                new UsernameNotFoundException("username [" + username + "] not found in database")
        );
    }

}
```

*My `UserRepository` definition*

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

}
```

*My `User` entity*

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Singular
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Transient
    public Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.roles.stream()
                .map(Role::getAuthorities)
                .flatMap(Set::stream)
                .map(authority -> {
                    return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getPermission());
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return this.accountNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return this.accountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return this.credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean accountNonExpired = true;

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean enabled = true;

    @Override
    public void eraseCredentials() {
        this.password = null;
    }

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Timestamp createdDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp lastModifiedDate;

}
```

`schema.sql` - Creates a table used by the OAuth2 classes in Spring Security for persistent token storage

```
CREATE TABLE oauth2_authorized_client (
    client_registration_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    principal_name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    access_token_type varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    access_token_value blob NOT NULL,
    access_token_issued_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    access_token_expires_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    access_token_scopes varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
    refresh_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
    refresh_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (client_registration_id, principal_name)
);
```

The log output from my `LoginFormController` looks like this when I login via Facebook OAuth2 using my own Facebook account:

```
[INFO ] LoginFormController - USER AUTHENTICATED WITH OAUTH2
[INFO ] LoginFormController - auth token 'authorized client registration id': [facebook]
[INFO ] LoginFormController - auth token 'name': [10139295061993788]
[INFO ] LoginFormController - oauth2User 'name': [10139295061993788]
[INFO ] LoginFormController - oauth2User 'id' attribute value: [10139295061993788]
[INFO ] LoginFormController - oauth2User 'name' attribute value: [Jim Tough]
[INFO ] LoginFormController - oauth2User 'email' attribute value: [jim@jimtough.com]
```

I also see this log output from another listener class of mine:

```
[INFO ] AuthenticationEventLogger - principal type: OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken | authorities: [ROLE_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_public_profile]
```

The authorities `ROLE_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_public_profile` are meaningless in the context of my application.

---

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper`

You register a bean that will map your authorities to roles to be used.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                    .userAuthoritiesMapper(this.userAuthoritiesMapper())
                    ...
                )
            );
    }

    private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                if (OidcUserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority)authority;

                    OidcIdToken idToken = oidcUserAuthority.getIdToken();
                    OidcUserInfo userInfo = oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo();

                    // Map the claims found in idToken and/or userInfo
                    // to one or more GrantedAuthority's and add it to mappedAuthorities

                } else if (OAuth2UserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    OAuth2UserAuthority oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority)authority;

                    Map<String, Object> userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();

                    // Map the attributes found in userAttributes
                    // to one or more GrantedAuthority's and add it to mappedAuthorities

                }
            });

            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }
}
```

It can also be mapped as a bean and automatically picked up by spring boot configuration.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
    }

    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities).

Comment: Thanks @Toerktumlare! I'll explore what you've recommended. If this works out I'll come back and accept your answer.

Comment: @JimTough did it work?

Comment: Did not work for me. I gave up on this approach for OAuth2 integration.

Comment: @JimTough so what is the alternative? I'm on my 3rd day into solving this and getting desperate :)

Comment: @ligett - Sorry fellow coder, but I abandoned this POC project and moved on to something else  :(